# Why array variable names have magic? What is this for?

Tags: perl, perl-xs

Fetching the name of variable from `PAD_COMPNAME` shows that the name is magical:

```
SV *sv =  PadnameSV( PAD_COMPNAME( cPADOP->targ +ix ) );
do_sv_dump( 0, Perl_debug_log, sv, 0, 10, 0, 0 );

SV = PV(0x1c1ed40) at 0x1c1bb30
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x19eb480 "@y"\0 [UTF8 "@y"]
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 10
  MAGIC = 0x1a58340
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_arylen_p
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_arylen_p(@)
    MG_FLAGS = 0x02
      REFCOUNTED
    MG_LEN = 8
    MG_PTR = 0x19eb460 "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  ARRAY = 0x0
  FILL = -1
  MAX = -1
  ARYLEN = 0x0
  FLAGS = (REAL)
```

Why we need magic for variable name? What is this for?

Comment: `arylen` seems to be documented in [perlguts](http://p3rl.org/perlguts), but I don't understand the details (and you provided no context).

Comment: @choroba: I thought that variable names are exists only to get the bare name of variable. I was surprised when saw that variable name is something more than just bare name.

Comment: @choroba, The magic in the OP is `arylen_p` (`@`), not `arylen` (`#`)

Comment: `arylen_p` appears to be related to `arylen`. `arylen` is used for `$#a = 123;`. I don't see how it's possible for it to be on something other than an `AV`.  Only one function adds and looks up that magic (`S_get_aux_mg` in `av.c`), and it asserts that it's the parameter is an array (`assert(SvTYPE(av) == SVt_PVAV);`).

Comment: @ikegami: Another thing I have notice. When I `sv_dump` tied array from `XSUB` the `MyObj::Array::FETCHSIZE` is triggered. It is strange because dumping should not trigger any events. But likely something wrong in my `XSUB`. ([just for reference](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/566540))